# Unable to proceed further with testing search using Python in Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am new to forum so pardon me if I missed on any etiquette of this forum. I am learner in writing automation scripts using Python in Selenium Webdriver.

Here I am trying to write a simple code to go to lowes.com/stores --> enter a zip code in search box --> click find button and see the result. 
When I am using the below code to do this, I am successful in entering zip code in search box, but nothing is happening after that. When I tried to click on Find button manually on the automated browser, it says We are sorry, please try again later. I have pasted the below code. 
I have also tried to find the find button using full xpath, class, value, but no success. Could you please guide me in right direction. (currently I have not given assertion and EC library, but I was expecting below simple code to work).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.lowes.com/store/")
search_box = driver.find_element_by_id("search-box")
search_box.send_keys(28262)
find_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="storeSearch"]/div/div/span/input')
find_button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Put wait and try it again:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.lowes.com/store/")
search_box = driver.find_element_by_id("search-box")
search_box.send_keys(28262)
    **put wait here**
    find_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="storeSearch"]/div/div/span/input')
    **put wait here** 
    find_button.click()
```